# How to run bash commands in a tox.ini command

Tags: bash, tox

Having a testenv in a tox.ini file, how do we execute bash commands?

```
[testenv:testenv_name]
description = testenv_description.
commands =
    export ABC="123"
    echo $ABC
```

Answer (score -2):

Partial answer:
Add the line *allowlist_externals = /bin/bash*. Then for calling the bash "commands", use */bin/* before the atual command; e.g.: **/bin/echo**.

Example:

```
[testenv:testenv_name]
description = testenv_description.
allowlist_externals = /bin/bash
commands =
    /bin/touch deleteme.txt
    /bin/echo -e "123\n456"
```

However commands such as *export* do not seem to work.

Comment: Don't waste your time with crapware like this.